# Internet Explorer Not Dropping LIst Down

Tags: html, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

When I run this code example:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select

in IE, the drop down list stays anchored to the last selection in the selection box, but when I use Firefox and Chrome the list drops down like it should.  Is this a quirk of IE and is there a way to make IE treat the code correctly.

Been googling this for awhile and can't seem to get the proper search terms to find a solution if any.  This also seems to happen to sites on the web as well.  Never noticed this before, but now that I'm trying to write html code its bugging the crap out of me.  Thanks.

Novice in html.

Comment: Works OK here. Which version(s) are you experiencing problems with? I tried with 8 + 9.

Comment: And you might want to check out > http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: It's just how IE(10?) renders the drop down. It's not a bug or anything. Dropdowns don't always drop down :)

Comment: Latest, IE 10.  I guess standardization just not for the browser world.

Answer (score 0):

I currently cant test this seeing as im working on OSX but this should work.

```
<select id="idSelect">
    <option value="line1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="line2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="test" onClick="test()" />
```

I found the information [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228).

Answer (score 0):

Add this :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

between your head tags.